# Mosfet driverless mosfet Slayer exciter (adjustable power)

Tags: mosfet, coil

I'm new to electronics but I tried to make mosfet slayer exciter anyways. Most of the mosfet slayer exciter I've seen uses mosfet driver to turn on the gate of the mosfet, but since I don't have access to mosfet driver, I decided to use BJT to turn on and off the gate of the mosfet. I came up with the schematic my own but since I'm a noob, it didn't work :< Am I going the right direction with this schematic? Or is there any mistake in my schematic? Any help is appreciated.
The potentiometer is tuned so the voltage divider creates 4.2V for mosfet gate.
The resonant frequency of the secondary is 810kHz and primary is tuned at resonant frequency as well. (do I even need the primary tank capacitor? because its self oscillating)
When powered on, the circuit draws about 1 amp and mosfet heats up a bit (not much) which is kind of expected but no high voltage on the secondary.[image]

Comment: I'm using Linear power supply so switching current problem should be fine

Comment: The problem with using a mosfet is the gate is effectively a capacitor that must be charged and discharged quickly... Going through a resistor the way you are will never turn it on and off.

Comment: Hi. I knew I should connect the pull down resistor to ground instead of secondary ground. I saw few design that did it like this and that's why I also did it like this as well. I'll give that a go. thanks!

Comment: that's irrelevant. Those resistors are way too large to properly pull the mosfet down to turn off at 800 kilohertz.

Comment: You really need a gate driver for this. and honestly when you start approaching the larger power levels where you need a mosfet, you might as well just build a half bridge Tesla coil.

Comment: Yeah your right. no matter how much I tried, the capacitance is too large. I got mosfet driver and it worked nice. I will make half bridge or H bridge in the future!